# IntelliJ IDEA: Move line?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

I really like IntelliJ IDEA's "Move statement" shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>). However -- I am not sure if this is a bug releated to ActionScript editing only -- move statement is not always what I want and sometimes it is not correct when editing AS code.

So I just want to move a block of lines up/down. The Eclipse shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> and does not move statement-wise. Is there an equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Open **Settings** -> **Keymap** then **search** for ***"move line"*** via the upper right searchbox.

Under the **Code** folder you'll see:

- **Move Statement Down**
- **Move Statement Up**
- **Move Line Down**
- **Move Line Up**

The actions you're looking for are (as you may guess) the move line actions.

Comment: On Mac I use alt+shift+up/down to move a line. However, the indentation of the line is kept and is not adjusted according to the indentation of the new scope. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: On Ubuntu I use alt+shift+up/down to move a line and that works fine.

Comment: BTW, `move statement` can't move a line out of its function, while `move line` could.

Comment: @user218867 Nope. `Move Statement` re-indent the selection, but `Move Line` not.

Answer (score 90):

As other people have said this is already available as a command.  You can configure the short cut to your liking, but by default (at least in IntelliJ 10) it is bound to <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd>

Comment: I know this is from a while ago, but CTRL + SHIFT + UP/DOWN will obey tab structure as the line moves in the editor.  This is especially useful when the code moves through various scopes, as a lot of programmers (all?) use different indentation per scope.

Answer (score 9):

shift + alt + ↑/↓

you can find All short cuts  HERE

https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The LineMover plug-in works very well and is an acceptable solution.

Comment: Very simple, I use this all the time;  it binds to 
Control-Shift-Up
Control-Shift-Down

Comment: There is no need for this plugin as mentioned elsewhere Alt+Shift+Up and down perform this action.

Answer (score 3):

Please find some useful shortcut for IntelliJ:

---

### (1) IntelliJ Debugger

Step over (Go To next Step or line) :  F8

Step into (Go into function) :  F7

Smart step into :  Shift + F7

Step out :  Shift + F8

Run to cursor : Alt + F9

Evaluate expression : Alt + F8

Resume program : F9 [Mac = Cmd + ALT + R]

Toggle breakpoint : Ctrl + F8 [Mac = Cmd + F8]

View breakpoints : Ctrl + Shift + F8 [Mac = Cmd + Shift + F8]

---

### (2) Open Specific File

Ctrl + Shift + N

---

### (3) Open All Methods Implemented in class

Open specific class and press,

Ctrl + F12

---

### (4) Go to Specific Line Number

Ctrl + G

---

### (5) Method Implementation and Declaration

Declaration : Ctrl + B

Implementation : Ctrl + Alt + B

Response Type Declaration : Ctrl + Shift + B

Super class override Method : Ctrl + U

---

### (6) Reformate Code

Ctrl + Alt + L

---

### (7) Import relevant class

Click on relevant class (Red color field) and press,

Alt + Enter

Select valid class as per requirement

---

### (8) Hierarchy of method calls

Select specific method and press,

Ctrl + Alt + H

---

### (9) Comment In Code

Single Line : Select specific line and press, 
Ctrl + /

Multiple Line : Select Multiple Line and Press,
Ctrl + Shift + /

(Note : Same operation for uncomment the code)

---

### (10) Display Line Number

Hit Shift twice > write "line" > Show Line Numbers (the line doesn't have the toggle)

View > Active Editor > Show Line Number

---

### (11) Code Selection

Full class selection : Ctrl + A
Method Selection : Select Method Name and press, Ctrl + W

---

### (12) Basic Code Completion

To complete methods, keywords etc press,

Ctrl + Space

---

### (13) Code Copy and Paste

Copy : Ctrl + C

Paste : Ctrl + V

---

### (14) Search Operation

Specific File : Ctrl + F

Full Project : Ctrl + Shift + F

---

### (15) Switcher Popup

Open Switcher Popup : Ctrl + Tab

Continue press Ctrl and use ↑/↓/←/→ for move one place to another

---

### (16) Forward Move & Backward Move

Backward : Ctrl + Alt + ← (Left-Arrow)

Forward : Ctrl + Alt + → (Right-Arrow)

---

### (17) Next/previous highlighted error

F2 or (Shift + F2)

---

### (18) Open Java Doc

Select specific method name and press,

Ctrl + Q

---

### (19) Find All commands

Ctrl + Shift + A

---

### (20) Move Line Up/Down

shift + alt + ↑/↓

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

try command+shift+up/down this will auto adjust the indentation

Answer (score -1):

You can move several lines together with move statement.  Are you trying to move partial lines?  I don't think there's a way in Idea.

Comment: As I said in the question, move statement is not what I need but an equivalent to Eclipse's move line. I also found the LineMover plug-in for IDEA. Maybe that will work.